# Manejo de ventanas emergentes

Tags: jquery

Me encuentro realizando la programación de unos íconos con `jquery` y bueno ya en el `html` ya tengo estructuradas unas ventanas las cuales en el `css` ya les pongo la propiedad `display:none` pero ya que se encuentran todas programadas para que cuando se realice un click sobre cada icono se visualicen y cuando los pruebo se abren dos ventanas a la vez y la otra no lo hace.

```
<script src="JS/jquery-3_6-min.js"></script>
<div class="ventana_buscador" id="ventanaBuscador">
               <div class="ventana-btn">
                  <i class="icon-left-big cerrarFlecha" id="btn_cerrar_buscador"></i>
               </div>
               <input type="search" name="consulta" id="inputSearch" placeholder="¿Qué deseas buscar?">
               <div id="datosBusqueda">

               </div>
<div class="ventana_login" id="login_ventana">
            <i class="icon-cancel cerrar-ventana-login" id="btn_cerrar_login"></i>
            <div class="tituloLogin">
               <h1>Iniciar sesión</h1>
            </div>
            <form class="login_form" id="login_form"> <!-- action="login.php" method="post" -->
               <table class="formLogin">
                  <tr class="form_input">
                     <td class="loginDescripcion">
                        <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                     </td>
                     <td class="loginCasillero">
                        <div class="form-login-input">
                           <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario" required>
                           <i class="formulario-input-error icon-attention-alt" id="usuario-icono"></i>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" class="form_mensaje_error" id="mensaje_loginUsu-error">Solo letras, caractéres especiales y/o números</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="espacio-login"></tr>
                  <tr class="form_input">
                     <td class="loginDescripcion">
                        <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
                     </td>
                     <td class="loginCasillero">
                        <div class="form-login-input">
                           <input type="password" name="passw" id="passw" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required minlength="8" maxlength="12">
                           <i class="formulario-input-error icon-attention-alt" id="contrasenia-icono"></i>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" class="form_mensaje_error" id="mensaje_loginPass-error">Mínimo 8 caractéres</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="espacio-login"></tr>
               </table>
               <div class="form_submit">
                  <input type="submit" name="acceder" value="Acceder"  id="btn_submit-login" onclick="javascript: accedeLogin()">
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="ventana_carrito" id="carrito_ventana">
            <a href="#"  id="btn_cerrar_carrito" class="cerrar-ventana-carrito"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
            <!-- <i class="icon-cancel cerrar-ventana-emergente" id="btn_cerrar_carrito"></i> -->
            <div class="contenerdorPRS">
            </div>
            <div class="totales">
               <div class="t_descrip">
                  <label>Total :</label>
               </div>
               <div class="t_valor">
                  <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                  <label class="price-total">0.00</label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-enter">
               <input type="submit" name="comprar" value="comprar">
            </div>
         </div>
```

```
.cover_principal {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   z-index: 35;
   display: none;
}
.claseVisible {
   display: block;
}
.ventana_buscador {
   position: fixed;
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1700px;
   font-size: 13px;
   transition: all 600ms;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   z-index: 40;
   display: none;
}
.ventana_login {
   width: 405px;
   background: #0033CC;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 3px;
   border: 2px solid #FFF;
   padding: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   z-index: 40;
   display: none;
}
.ventana_carrito {
   width: 460px;
   background: #FFF;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 40px 10px 20px;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   position: relative;
   z-index: 40;
   display: none;
}
```

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
   let btn = e.target.id;
   // console.log(btn);
   switch (btn) {
      case "vBuscar":
         $("#coverPrincipal").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#ventanaBuscador").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#login_ventana").removeClass("claseVisible");
         $("#carrito_ventana").removeClass("claseVisible");
         break;
      case "vSesion":
         $("#coverPrincipal").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#login_ventana").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#ventanaBuscador").removeClass("claseVisible");
         $("#carrito_ventana").removeClass("claseVisible");
         break;
      case "vCarrito":
         $("#coverPrincipal").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#carrito_ventana").addClass("claseVisible");
         $("#ventanaBuscador").removeClass("claseVisible");
         $("#login_ventana").removeClass("claseVisible");
         break;
   }
});
```

[image: resultado de lo que tengo actualmente]

**¿Qué puedo modificar para que cada icono muestre solo la ventana correspondiente encima del coverPrincipal?**

Comment: Buenas noches. No entiendo por qué sería necesarios abrir dos modales o ventanas al mismo tiempo. Sería mejor insertar el buscador dentro del mismo modal principal y partir de ahí mostrar u ocultar el buscador. Es más simple y fácil esteticamente

Comment: No es necesario abrir dos; solo digo que cuando hago click en un icono a pesar de que en el ``jquery`` he definido que se visualice un solo modal, se activan dos.

Comment: Ya solucionaste? Si se abre dos modales con un solo llamado (click) es porque los dos modales tienen el mismo **id**. Si no es así, agrega tu html para analizar

Comment: No, todavía no lo soluciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi que falta cerrar el  de ventana_buscar y por eso te hacia lo de mostrar dos a la vez y la tercera no y así y con la corrección del jquery modificas la propiedad del css y no se la añades con una clase que eso daba problemas, espero que te sirva la solución. Un saludo :)

```js
'use strict'

        $('body').on('click', function(e){
        let btn = e.target.id;
        // console.log(btn);
        switch (btn) {
        case "vBuscar":

        $(".ventana_buscador").css("display", 'block');
        $(".cover_principal").css("display", 'block');
        $(".ventana_login").css("display", 'none');
        $(".ventana_carrito").css("display", 'none');

        break;
        case "vSesion":
        $(".cover_principal").css("display", 'block');
        $(".ventana_login").css("display", 'block');
        $(".ventana_buscador").css("display", 'none');
        $(".ventana_carrito").css("display", 'none');
        break;
        case "vCarrito":
        $(".cover_principal").css("display", 'block');
        $(".ventana_carrito").css("display", 'block');
        $(".ventana_buscador").css("display", 'none');
        $(".ventana_login").css("display", 'none');
        break;
    }
    });
```

```css
.cover_principal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 35;
    display:none;
}
.claseVisible {
    display: block;
}
.ventana_buscador {
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1700px;
    font-size: 13px;
    transition: all 600ms;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 40;
    display: none;
}
.ventana_login {
    width: 405px;
    background: #0033CC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 40;
    display:none;
}
.ventana_carrito {
    width: 460px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 40px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery-3_6-min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <button id="vBuscar">Buscar</button>
    <button id="vSesion">Sesion</button>
    <button id="vCarrito">Carrito</button>

</nav>

<div class="ventana_buscador" id="ventanaBuscador">
    <div class="ventana-btn">
        <i class="icon-left-big cerrarFlecha" id="btn_cerrar_buscador"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="search" name="consulta" id="inputSearch" placeholder="¿Qué deseas buscar?">
    <div id="datosBusqueda">

    </div>
</div>
    <div class="ventana_login" id="login_ventana">
        <i class="icon-cancel cerrar-ventana-login" id="btn_cerrar_login"></i>
        <div class="tituloLogin">
            <h1>Iniciar sesión</h1>
        </div>
        <form class="login_form" id="login_form"> <!-- action="login.php" method="post" -->
            <table class="formLogin">
                <tr class="form_input">
                    <td class="loginDescripcion">
                        <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="loginCasillero">
                        <div class="form-login-input">
                            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario" required>
                            <i class="formulario-input-error icon-attention-alt" id="usuario-icono"></i>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="form_mensaje_error" id="mensaje_loginUsu-error">Solo letras, caractéres especiales y/o números</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="espacio-login"></tr>
                <tr class="form_input">
                    <td class="loginDescripcion">
                       <!-- <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label> -->
                    </td>
                    <td class="loginCasillero">
                        <div class="form-login-input">
                            <input type="password" name="passw" id="passw" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required minlength="8" maxlength="12">
                            <i class="formulario-input-error icon-attention-alt" id="contrasenia-icono"></i>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="form_mensaje_error" id="mensaje_loginPass-error">Mínimo 8 caractéres</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="espacio-login"></tr>
            </table>
            <div class="form_submit">
                <input type="submit" name="acceder" value="Acceder"  id="btn_submit-login" onclick="javascript: accedeLogin()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ventana_carrito" id="carrito_ventana">
        <a href="#"  id="btn_cerrar_carrito" class="cerrar-ventana-carrito"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
        <!-- <i class="icon-cancel cerrar-ventana-emergente" id="btn_cerrar_carrito"></i> -->
        <div class="contenerdorPRS">
        </div>
        <div class="totales">
            <div class="t_descrip">
                <label>Total :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="t_valor">
                <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                <label class="price-total">0.00</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-enter">
            <input type="submit" name="comprar" value="comprar">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```